# ffmpeg output to framebuffer (fbdev) Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: ffmpeg, raspbian, framebuffer, raspberry-pi4

I have been trying to play a video on the frame buffer with ffmpeg. In theory this

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -pix_fmt bgra -f fbdev /dev/fb0
```

I get errors like

```
[fbdev @ 0xfcb380] Pixel format bgra is not supported, use rgb565le
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
```

or
Interlace errors when I use rgb565le.

Confusingly when I try to read from the framebuffer, I get a screenshot of incorrect resolution which looks like a blank tty.

```
sudo ffmpeg -f fbdev -framerate 1 -i /dev/fb0 -frames:v 1 screenAA3.jpeg
```

I am running on a RPi4 with latest buster build. I have had issues with graphical packages not working with the post vulkan driver, could that be the issue?

Comment: What is the output from running `fbset` ?